# As I can compile a project of Cocos2D-X?

Tags: android, cocos2d-x

I'm trying to compile a project and when I run andriod on brand me this error terminal

./build_native.sh: line 89: :/Users/dark6425/Documents/android-ndk-r8/ndk-build: No such file or directory

and check the path and file if this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define the environment $NDK_ROOT variable properly. Did you have android-ndk in the path you've mentioned(that came in error message)?

> /Users/dark6425/Documents/android-ndk-r8